# Google Sheet to Firebase - sync data

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, firebase-realtime-database

[First Post in stackoverflow]

I followed this video tutorial to sync data between Google Sheets and Firebase Realtime Database. Video tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nivSPsDyHHY

Unfortunately, the owner of the video has disabled comments in the video so could not clarify it there.

So, here is the source code I am using in Apps Scripts:

```
    function syncData() {
   const email = "email.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
   const key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\Lorem Ipsum\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
   const projectId = "pasted from JSON file as shown in video";
   var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);
}

// get document data from ther spreadsheet
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetname = "Sheet1";
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
   // get the last row and column in order to define range
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row
   var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); // get the last columnvar dataSR = 2; // the first row of data
   // define the data range
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);// get the data
   var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
   // get the number of length of the object in order to establish a loop value
   var sourceLen = sourceData.length;

   // Loop through the rows
   for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
     if(sourceData[i][1] !== '') {
       var data = {};
       var dateSt = sourceData[i][0].toString();
       var stDate = new Date(dateSt);
       var stringfied = JSON.stringify(stDate);
       var updatedDt = stringfied.slice(1,11);
       data.date = updatedDt;
       data.country = sourceData[i][1];
       data.name = sourceData[i][2];
       data.state = sourceData[i][3];
       data.mob_no = sourceData[i][4];
       data.raw_data = sourceData[i][5];
        
       firestore.createDocument("firebase DB name",data);   }
    
  }
```

Every time I run the code, it throws an error (screenshot attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsW1Y.png)

`Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null (anonymous) @ Code.gs.11`

Also, I am not a core developer. Just want to simulate an use case to syncdata between Google Sheet and Firebase. Please help!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try putting everything in one function

Comment: @BigBen: It did not work.